# sencha touch 2 RoutingError (No route matches "/docs")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am ror developer.

As per http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started

I have downloaded sencha touch library and put unzipped directory in 
public directory, and renamed it as touch.

my application runs at http://localhost:3000/

when I try to access http://localhost:3000/touch

it gives me error as RoutingError (No route matches "/docs") and

url in browser changes to http://localhost:3000/docs

Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a forwarding code in the index.html file to `Redirect non-mobile devices to docs/`.

removing this script(line 13-16) from index.html fix the redirecting problem and as you see redirected route is not on **http://localhost:3000/docs** . it is on the **http://localhost:3000/touch/docs**

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for instant reply. It now shows me sencha welcome page but no image and proper layout as shown in image at documentation site. Also when I click on View Example its giving me error as No route matches "/examples".                                               Do I need to do more than just copying unzipped folder in public directory?

Comment: I tried to change /example/ in same file to public/touch/examples/view/, but didn't worked.

Comment: I just unzipped in apache server. And open http://localhost:3000/touch/docs, it works. My suggestion is check why in your links removed /touch path. you must access /touch/example instead /example.

Comment: Thanks ykartal, I manually entered url as http://localhost:3000/touch/examples then it given me list of examples with blank images.                    And when I click on any example it says no route matches to that example.                                                          Also if I manually enter url as touch/examples/ajax it gives me blank page without any error

Comment: Maybe There is a problem with your system or server behavior. May any htaccess or something cause this? I think your server open example/ as {root}/example. Maybe you could try to add /examples/kitchensink/ instead examples/kitchensink/ on line 50 in index.html to access with clicking

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5457/discussion-between-ykartal-and-swapnil-chincholkar)